# Clear text when you press the JTextField

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm trying to get the text of the JTextField erased every time I click on it. I made a `addFocusListene`But no word comes out. I do not understand why

```
        nick = new JTextField("nick", 5);
    add(nick);
    nick.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            nick.setText("");

        }

        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            // nothing
        }
    });

    JLabel texto = new JLabel("CLIENTE");
    add(texto);

    ip = new JTextField("Introduce la IP del destinatario", 16);
    add(ip);
    ip.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            ip.setText("");

        }

        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            // nothing
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear JTextField when mouse clicks the JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133366/how-to-clear-jtextfield-when-mouse-clicks-the-jtextfield)

Comment: A FocusListener should work, and in fact you could use the same listener on all your JTextFields by using the FocusEvent's source field. I can't say why it's not working for you and ask that you post a more complete [mcve] program that shows us your problem.

Comment: `new FocusAdapter() { public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) { ((JTextComponent) e.getSource()).setText(""); }}` should work for all

Comment: The comment about "no text comes out" makes me wonder if your asking something different.  Do you need anything else to happen besides clearing the text field?

Comment: `FocusEvent` is not the needed one, as it would not fire if the editor already has the focus....

Comment: `I'm trying to get the text of the JTextField erased every time I click on it` - well that would be annoying. First I type something and tab to another field. Then I realize I made a typing mistake and go back to the text field to fix it, only to have all the test be deleted? I suspect you might want something like the [Text Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/), which allows you to display a prompt in the text field that is removed when the user enters some text.